# jQuery UI Spinner Up Down event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI spinner and I want to know if the spin is up or down I have tried using:

```
$('#days').spinner({
    min:0,
    spin: function(event, ui){
        console.log(ui.value);
        $day = ui.value;
        //Now here I want to detect if the event is up or down and perform 
         another function according to event type
    }
)};
```

This is my code,but the event is not specific to up or down
I want to detect if its up or down so that I can perform accordingly to these events.Thanks

Comment: `to determine direction of spin compare current value with ui.value` from jquery ui spinner documentation

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Cerlin Boss , You need to compare old spinner value with the new changed value,

```
 $("#days").spinner({
    spin : function(event,ui){
        //Gives Previous value
        console.log($(this).val());
        //Gives current value
        console.log(ui.value);
        if($(this).val()<ui.value){
            console.log("Increment");
        }else             
           console.log("decrement");
    }
});
```

#### See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNys7/106/)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Class of spin Up button
$to_element = $(event.toElement).hasClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-n'); 
//SPIN UP if true else SPIN DOWN
if($to_element){
    //ADD
}
else{
    //Subtract
}
```

@ Cerlin Boss and @ Runcorn I tried this and its working,Should I use this or as your answer?

Comment: It seems OK and a nice approach for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on use. The best way seems to be comparing values, but there could be a case with using strings. I needed in the shop script flow like "Item count: 1>2>3>individual pricing". In this case @BulletProof47 was great, yet it didn't work with jQuery 2.1.4. I had problem with event element class. I had to change it to:

```js
if ($(event.currentTarget).hasClass('ui-spinner-down')) {
    console.log('down');
    return false;
    }

if ($(event.currentTarget).hasClass('ui-spinner-up')) {
    console.log('up');
    return false;
    }
```

PS: I'd just answer post, but I can't yet. And hello, it's my first post :)

Answer (score 0):

To determine the direction of spin compare the ui.value and current value.

```
    //doc ready
$('#days').spinner({
    min:0,
    spin: function(event, ui){

        var $operation = "none";//no operation happens when value of spinner is Zero

        if($(this).val() != ui.value){
            //overide
            if( ui.value < $(this).val() ){
                $operation = "down";
            }else{
                $operation = "up";
            }               

        } 


        //just for UI
        $('#operation').val($operation)
    }
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/redhot2323/gqjvyajj/)